# Get the all sub sites from a site collection along with site hierarchy using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sub-site

I had site collection is SharePoint online with the below hierarchy.

[image]

The value in the bracket is the site hierarchy (added for understanding only). 
I want to get all the subsite details along with Hierarchy level. I am able to get all the subsite details with the below code.

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(destinationSiteUrl))
                {
                    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, secure);
                    DataTable dtsubsites = new DataTable();
                    Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
                    clientContext.Load(oWebsite.Webs);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Dictionary<int, Web> mydict = new Dictionary<int, Web>();
                    var allWebs = new List<Web>();
                    var objallWebs = LoadAllWebs(clientContext.Site.RootWeb, allWebs);
                    foreach (var web in objallWebs)
                    {
                        ddlsubsites.Items.Add(web.Url.ToString());
                    }                    
                }

 public  List<Web> LoadAllWebs(Web web, List<Web> allWebs)
        {           
            var ctx = web.Context;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.Load(web.Webs);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            allWebs.Add(web);         
            foreach (var subWeb in web.Webs)
            {
                LoadAllWebs(subWeb, allWebs);               
            }           
            return allWebs;
        }
```

How to get the hierarchy level of each site? Any Suggestions, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `allWebs` into a list containing level+Web

Add a `int level` parameter to `LoadAllWebs`

In the first call pass 0 as `level`.
In the recursive call inside `LoadAllWebs` pass `level+1`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. can you please explain a little more. means to use List<Tuple<T1, T2>> list  or list<class>

Answer (score 4):

Here's a approach based of the Search which should be way **faster** and more **ressource friendly**.

It currently only groups subwebs after rootwebs, but could easily modified to also group the subwebs.

**Result:**

```
[ 22.04.2016 11:41:02 ] Infrastructure found by Search:
https://rootSPDomain.de
       https://rootSPDomain.de
       https://rootSPDomain.de/SubWeb1
       https://rootSPDomain.de/SubWeb1/SubWeb1
       https://rootSPDomain.de/SubWeb2
       https://rootSPDomain.de/SubWeb2/SubWeb1
```

**Code:**

```
    private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetAllWebsBySearch(ref int errorCount)
    {
        var webUrls = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext(Settings.Default.SearchCenterUrl))
            {
                var sites = SearchWebs(ctx, Settings.Default.SearchQuery + " contentclass:STS_Site");
                var webs = SearchWebs(ctx, Settings.Default.SearchQuery + " contentclass:STS_Web");

                if (sites.Count == 0)
                    Log.ThrowCritical(string.Format("No sites found for searchstring '{0}'",
                        Settings.Default.SearchQuery));

                foreach (var site in sites)
                    webUrls.Add(site, new List<string> { site });

                foreach (var web in webs)
                {
                    var parentSite = sites.Where(site => web.StartsWith(site)).OrderByDescending(s => s.Length).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (parentSite != null)
                    {
                        if (!webUrls[parentSite].Contains(web))
                            webUrls[parentSite].Add(web);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.Error(string.Format("Could not find site for web {0}", web));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(string.Format("Error while searching webs at {0}",
                Settings.Default.SearchCenterUrl));
            Log.Error(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", ex.Message));
            errorCount++;
        }
        return webUrls;
    }

    private static List<string> SearchWebs(ClientContext ctx, string query)
    {
        var returnValue = new List<string>();
        var rowLimit = 500;
        var startRow = 0;
        var allResultsFetched = false;
        var fieldPath = "Path";

        while (!allResultsFetched)
        {
            Log.Verbose(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Search with query - {0}", query));
            var keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(ctx)
            {
                QueryText = query,
                RowLimit = rowLimit
            };
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Clear();
            keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add(fieldPath);
            keywordQuery.StartRow = startRow;
            keywordQuery.TrimDuplicates = false;

            var searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(ctx);
            var results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
            {
                var path = resultRow.Keys.Contains(fieldPath) && (resultRow[fieldPath] != null)
                    ? resultRow[fieldPath].ToString()
                    : string.Empty;
                returnValue.Add(path);
            }

            if (results.Value[0].RowCount < rowLimit)
                allResultsFetched = true;
            else
                startRow = startRow + rowLimit + 1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    private static void LogInfrastructure(Dictionary<string, List<string>> webInfrastructure)
    {
        var message = "Infrastructure found by Search:\n";
        foreach (var site in webInfrastructure)
        {
            message += site.Key + "\n";
            foreach (var web in site.Value)
                message += "\t" + web + "\n";
            message += "\n";
        }

        Log.Message(message);
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
//get all web urls from the search
var webInfrastructure = GetAllWebsBySearch(ref errorCount);
LogInfrastructure(webInfrastructure);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Per Jakobsen](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/990/per-jakobsen) solution worked for me. Please find the below code for  reference

```
     using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(destinationSiteUrl))
       {
         clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, secure);
         DataTable dtsubsites = new DataTable();
         Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
         clientContext.Load(oWebsite.Webs);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         var listclass = new List<webdetails>();
         var allWebs = new List<Web>();
         var objallWebs = LoadAllWebs(clientContext.Site.RootWeb, listclass, 0);
         GridView1.DataSource = objallWebs.ToList();
         GridView1.DataBind();
       }

 public class webdetails
  {
     public string csomweb { get; set; }
     public Int32 webhirarchy { get; set; }
  }

 public List<webdetails> LoadAllWebs(Web web, List<webdetails> allWebs,int level)
        {
            var ctx = web.Context;
            ctx.Load(web);
            ctx.Load(web.Webs);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            // allWebs.Add(web);
            allWebs.Add(new webdetails { csomweb = web.Title, webhirarchy = level });
            foreach (var subWeb in web.Webs)
            {
                LoadAllWebs(subWeb, allWebs, level+1);
            }
            return allWebs;
        }
```